# Pandas DataFrame Groupby Operations with np.nan in a by= series

Tags: python, pandas

I recently came across a situation in a large dataset whereby one of my `groupby` series contained a few `np.nan` values. This causes the observation to be dropped from the results table. In a high dimensional case (>100,000 lines) this can be sometimes tricky to identify and this results in systematic loss of data. I have now become a lot more focused on my groupby items and use the minimum index information to identify unique cases prior to `sum()`.

**A simple example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
tuples = list(zip(*[['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz',
                     'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
                     [np.nan, np.nan, 'one', 'two',
                     'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

produces the following `DataFrame`

[image: untitled]

When doing `GroupBy` Operations

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2.groupby(['first', 'second']).sum()
#OR
df.groupby(level=['first', 'second']).sum()
```

We get the resulting `DataFrame`

[image: untitled]

This makes good sense from a `default` perspective (due to incomplete information) but it would be nice to have the option not to discard `bar` and leave the data as is, which in this case would return the `original dataframe`.

This situation arose in my data because I had a redundant index item that didn't vary at the lower levels of a `MultiIndex` so I didn't think it would mater (as it was nice to retain in the data set as a different representation of another index item: It was `FullCountryName` and `ISO3C` code), however I found that because it wasn't defined in one country case it therefore dropped that country from the resulting dataframe (without any warnings).

Is there a way to achieve this outcome?

Perhaps a `warning` should be issued in the event of dropping a group due to the presence of `np.nan` at any level.

### Update

This probably makes it clearer as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tuples = list(zip(*[['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz',
                     'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux',],
                     ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two',
                     'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                     [np.nan, np.nan, 'one', 'two', 
                      'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second', 'third'])
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

produces the following dataframe

[image]

then

```
df.groupby(level=['first', 'second', 'third']).sum()
```

produces:

[image]

where the `third` level doesn't matter in the uniqueness of the groupby.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. Didn't see that one in my search. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: You can just leave it, it can serve as a signpost for others who have this problem and find their way to this question.